# How to add arrays to another array with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I want to add a set of arrays into the existing array with the same key. I can make those data out from db. But I cannot put them together to work.

**DB**

[image: option_unit]

**PHP**

```
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare("select * from option_unit order by level asc");
$stmt->execute();
$res=$stmt->get_result();           
    while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){
        $_parent=$row['parent'];            
                //child
                $_chl=$mysqli->prepare("select * from option_unit where parent=?");
                $_chl->bind_param('i',$_parent);
                $_chl->execute();
                $res1=$_chl->get_result();
                while($row1=$res1->fetch_assoc()){
                    $chld[]=array("head"=>$row['title'],"id"=>$row['id'],"contents"=>$row['title'],"children"=>"");
                }                   
                $_chl->close();                 
                
                $data[]=array("head"=>$row['title'],"id"=>$row['id'],"contents"=>$row['title'],"children"=>$chld);
        
            }//while

$stmt->close();
echo json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**JSON** (The result is duplicated hundred of lines)

[image: JSON result]

But what I expected to outcome is:

```
[
    {
        "head": "CEO",
        "id": 24,
        "contents": "CEO",
        "children": [
            {
                "head": "Accountant",
                "id": 2,
                "contents": "CEO",
                "children": [{ "head": "Manager", "id": "25", "contents": "Mr.Bill" }]
            },{
                "head": "HR",
                "id": 9,
                "contents": "CEO",
                "children": ""
            }
    }
    ]
```

I think there must be something wrong to the adding array. But I don't know what is it. If I know this one. Another tier of children would be easier.

Comment: you can use recursion for the same.

Comment: I have a hard time believing that 2023 is the first year where a developer wished to make recursive queries and build a multidimensional array with parent-child relationships.  Sample input data should not be presented as a screenshot (ever).  You could even use phpize.online to prepopulate a sample database for volunteers.

Answer (score 1):

You never declare `$chld` nor are you resetting it.

```php
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare("select * from option_unit order by level asc");
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();

while ($row=$res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $_parent = $row['parent'];
    //child
    $_chl = $mysqli->prepare("select * from option_unit where parent=?");
    $_chl->bind_param('i', $_parent);
    $_chl->execute();
    $res1 = $_chl->get_result();
    $chld = [];
    while ($row1 = $res1->fetch_assoc()) {
        $chld[]=[
            "head" => $row1['title'],
            "id" => $row1['id'],
            "contents" => $row1['title'],
            "children" => ""];
    }
    $_chl->close();

    $data[]=[
        "head" => $row['title'],
        "id" => $row['id'],
        "contents" => $row['title'],
        "children" => $chld];
}//while

$stmt->close();
echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Your code is looking good but I put the wrong query for the second loop. Instead of $row['parent']. I should search for $row['id'] because the column 'parent' linking to the 'id'.

Answer (score 1):

You can create recursive function this way so it can manage all the levels that you are expecting.

```php
function get_data($mysqli, $parent=0)
{
    if($parent === 0) {
        $stmt=$mysqli->prepare("select * from option_unit where parent=0 order by level asc");
    } else {
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select * from option_unit where parent=?");
        $stmt->bind_param('i',$_parent);
    }

    $stmt->execute();
    $data = [];
    $res=$stmt->get_result();           
    while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){
        $_parent=$row['id'];
        $child = get_data($mysqli, $_parent); 
        $data[]=array("head"=>$row['title'],"id"=>$row['id'],"contents"=>$row['title'],"children"=>$child);
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return $data;
}

$final_data = get_data($mysqli);
echo json_encode($final_data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Your method is interesting but I cannot make it to work. Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on null in line 11 -> $stmt=$mysqli->prepare("select * from option_unit order by level asc");

Comment: you can pass the `$mysqli` as it is not defined in `get_data`

Comment: Now I got another. Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted...

Comment: what will you have in parent id if there is no parent ? Also updating the answer as we need find records with id not the parent Id.

Comment: There's a top level unit (CEO in this case) who doesn't have a parent id. So only this guy got no reference.

Comment: doesn't have parent id means it has null or zero(0) ?

Comment: if it has zero then mentioned solution should work else you can update the first query to `select * from option_unit where parent is null order by level asc`

Comment: Doesn't have parent id means zero.

Comment: you should try the solution then which i have updated